# Could not inspect the application package when using device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I’m getting this error whenever I try to run my app on a device:

"App Installation Failed
Could not inspect the application package."

I realize that this can mean a million things and I have done days of research but nothing has worked yet. It works on the simulator.

What I’ve tried:

- Renaming “Resources” folder in the Google pod (only place it existed)
- Renaming “Resources” in Finder for Google and changing the path in the pods resource file
- Delete derived data (through projects window and deleting the folder directly)
- there are no weird characters in the product name (there is a space)
- delete derived data, delete app, restart phone, cmd+shift+K, quit Xcode, restart computer
- all software is up to date
- there are no sample projects from third parties
- the “capabilities” in the app match the entitlements in the app id

Other info:

- Xcode 6.4
- application supports iPhone and iPad (min version latest 8.4)
- works every time on the simulator
- always fails on the device (tested iPhone 6 and iPhone 5)
- builds with out error
- there is no run script printed (in “report navigator”) but there is for
  the build (again no error)
- valid architectures: arm64, armv7, armv7s, x86_64, i386
- build valid arch only: Debug-Y, Release-N

This was working fine before and I did a bunch of code changes (not settings) before this happened out of the blue.

Odd but has been happening:

- I’ve noticed that no matter how many times I switch the provisioning profile, it always switches back to automatic (kind of annoying but it isn’t my issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself. I was importing a framework in my bridging header that I previously removed and Xcode gave me no error I guess because I didn't call the framework anymore?

Steps:

- remove the unused/nonexistent framework for bridging header
- cmd+shift+k
- quit Xcode
- find your project's build folder and trash **the contents** of the Intermediates and Products folders
- open your project and run

This may be overkill but it works now. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For future reader:

Same issue, but different problem.

My problem in Cocoapods configuration.

I have update Cocoapods to latest version in main project, and in this version some configuration path has changed.

So, i need to make sure all my dynamic frameworks that use Cocoapods to be updated in same version to solve this issue.

Note:

- My latest Cocoapods version is 1.2.1
- Xcode v8.3.2
- update -> pod update

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an accidentally included framework. Just had to remove it.